# C++ : class A reference classe B (in a vector) and class B reference A (only one)

Tags: c++, class

**LAST EDIT: FINAL CODE LIES AT TH END OF THE MESSAGE**

i am coming from Java and I am looping for a while :

I try to implement navigability from classes Zoo to Animal and Animal to Zoo.

**Q.1) did I write it the right way ? (source code on bottom)**

I have got an compile error related to "stl_vector.h"
class Zoo : animals.push_back(a); 
with message : "error:cannot increment a pointeur to incomplete type Animal"

**Q.2 ) is it related to the way I implemented navigability ?**

In the main.cpp, i will add animals to the zoo :

```
Zoo z();
std::string nom("sheeta");
Animal a(z,nom);
```

**Q.3) the Animal constructor exists ... : why does the compiler tell me that**

compile error : "no matching function for call Animal::Animal(Zoo (&)(), std::string &)

**Q.4) what is the c++ way to write :**

```
z.addAnimal(Animal(z,nom));
```

**EDIT1 : here is what i want to implement : a zoo contains n animals, an animal knows which zoo it belongs to**

**LAST EDIT : picture updated with your help**
**==========================================**

[image]

many thanks for helping !

---

Here are the changes i made from your precious comments :

**LAST EDIT IN SOURCE CODE - 2015-12-18 07:20 gmt**
**===============================================**

file Zoo.h

```
#ifndef ZOO_H
#define ZOO_H

#include <vector>
```

** ADDED : include Animal.h **

```
#include "Animal.h"

class Zoo
{
  private:
    std::string zooName; // no importance : name of the zoo
    std::vector<Animal> animals;  // list of animals
  public:
    Zoo(std::string  n); // no importance : name of the zoo
```

** ADDED : const & **

```
    void addAnimal(Animal const & a); 
    std::vector<Animal>  getAnimals();
};

#endif
```

and Zoo.cpp :

```
#include "Zoo.h"
```

** REMOVED : include Animal.h

```
//#include "Animal.h"

Zoo::Zoo(std::string  n) // no importance, n is the name of the zoo
    {
        zooName = n;
```

** REMOVED : **

```
        //std::vector<Animal> animals(); // <<< REMOVED
    }
```

** ADDED : const & **

```
void Zoo::addAnimal(Animal const &a)    // <<<< const added
    {
        animals.push_back(a); // add an animal to the zoo
    }

std::vector<Animal> Zoo:: getAnimals()
    {
        return animals;
    }
```

And Animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>
```

** ADDED : forward declaration of Zoo **

```
class Zoo;
```

** REMOVED : include file

```
// #include "Zoo.h"    

class Animal
{
  private:
```

** CHANGED : pointer to Zoo **

```
    Zoo * zoo; // in which zoo   <<< CHANGED TO A POINTER
    std::string nom;  // name of an animal

  public:
```

** CHANGED : pointer to Zoo AND REMOVE & after string**

```
    // Animal(Zoo z, std::string & n); 
    Animal(Zoo * z, std::string n); 
    std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

And Animal.cpp :

```
#include "Animal.h"
```

** ADDED : include "Zoo.h"**

```
#include "Zoo.h"
#include <sstream> // ADDED TO CONVERT number to string
```

** CHANGED : pointer to Zoo AND REMOVED & after string**

```
//Animal::Animal(Zoo  z, std::string & n) // 
 Animal::Animal(Zoo * z, std::string  n) // 
    {  zoo = z; nom= n;
    }

std::string Animal::toString()
    {
```

** CHANGED : to justify the use of Zoo inside Animal **

```
    std::string msg1 (" among ");
    std::string msg3 (" other animals") ;
    // to convert number to string
        std::ostringstream chaine;
        chaine << zoo->getAnimals().size();
    std::string msg2(chaine.str());

    return (name+msg1+msg2+msg3);

    }
```

---

EDIT3 - And a main function to test these classes :

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Animal.h" 
 #include "Zoo.h"
 int main()
{
    std::string zooName("BigZoo");
    Zoo z(zooName);
    std::string nom;

    std::cin >> nom;
    while (nom.compare("*") != 0)
    {
```

**CHANGED : 2 lines deleted and 1 line added

```
    //    Animal a(&z,nom);
    //    z.addAnimal(a);
        z.addAnimal(Animal(&z, nom));
        std::cin >> nom;
    }

    for (unsigned int i=0;i<z.getAnimals().size(); i++)
    { // for each animal of the zoo
        std::cout << z.getAnimals().at(i).toString() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And a test to end :

```
>max 
>bill
>jumbo
>sheeta
>*
 max among 4 other animals
 bill among 4 other animals
 jumbo among 4 other animals
 sheeta among 4 other animals
```

**well done, stackoverflow is really great !!! thanks again**

---

**=====================================**

**FINAL HEADER CODE**

**=====================================**

```
/* Zoo.h */
#ifndef ZOO_H
#define ZOO_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Animal.h"

class Zoo
{
  private:
    std::string zooName;
    std::vector<Animal> animals;  // liste of animals
  public:
    Zoo(std::string  n);
    void addAnimal(Animal const & a);
    std::vector<Animal>  getAnimals();
};

#endif


/* Animal.h */

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>

class Zoo;

class Animal
{
  private:
    Zoo *zoo ; // in which zoo
    std::string name;  // name of an animal

  public:
    Animal(Zoo *z, std::string  n);
    std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

Comment: This is *4* questions in *1* question...

Comment: The `Zoo zoo` inside `Animal` is almost certainly not what you want.  It is a copy of the `Zoo` passed in.  I think you wanted `Zoo& zoo`

Comment: Zoo.cpp needs to include Animal.h, the failure to include that seems to be your main problem, so fix that first, then see what problems are left.  (Edit that fix and the remaining problems into your question if you still need help).

Comment: The following line in your `Zoo` constructor does not mean what you intend, and what you intend is done by default anyway, so just remove that line: `std::vector<Animal> animals(); // list of animals`

Comment: Returning by value from `getAnimals()` is horribly inefficient.  You probably want to return by `const&`.  Depending on your intended use of that function you may instead need the more error prone but more flexible return by non const `&`

Comment: As a general design pattern, one would expect Zoo.h to need to include Animal.h (rather than merely pre declare `Animal` in Zoo.h and include Animal.h in Zoo.cpp).  If that less general pattern works, great.  But as your code expends, it might no longer work.  But the flip side is more serious.  Animal.h **should** be properly coded so it can just pre declare `Zoo` and **NOT** include Zoo.h

Comment: Zoo zoo inside Animal is to know in whick zoo i san animal.

Comment: Why should `Animal` know which zoo it belongs to?

Comment: because Animal could ask for something to the zoo, for example " how many animals are there in the zoo at the moment..."...i checked that today, and they often do that ;-)

Comment: `Zoo z();` declares a function, not an object!  Google "Most Vexing Parse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. When declaring a `vector<Animal>` the `Animal` class has to be a complete class. Unlike Java, C++ stores the member elements by value and not by reference.

Q2 & Q3. `Zoo z();` declares a function taking no parameters and returning a `Zoo`. So you try to use a function name in the constructor of `Animal`. Doesn't work.

Q4. Creating a temporary parameter works, provided the `addAnimal` takes a const reference to the parameter - `void addAnimal(Animal const& a);`.

And, easy on the getters! Returning a copy (cloning?) of all the animals from the Zoo seems a bit much. What is the use of `getAnimals`, other than creating a new zoo?

Also, real animals at a zoo generally don't know which zoo they belong to. So having a reference in the `Animal` object seems a bit odd.

Also (2), `std::vector<Animal> animals();` is another function declaration, just like `Zoo z();`. You have to watch out for those.

Comment: ok and thanks for Q1 and Q2-Q3. / for Q4 : the main function can get all the animals from a zoo and print them for example

Answer (score 1):

`vector<Animal>` requires `Animal` to be a complete type at this point, so you need to change Zoo.h to `#include "Animal.h"`. In Animal.h you can forward declare `class Zoo;` But you also need to change the Animal member zoo to a reference `Zoo &zoo;`.

Comment: if i change class Animal to include "Animal.h" in Zoo.h, it tells : "Animal was not declared in this scope

Comment: @PatrickDezecache Please show your changed code (additionally to your original code). You can remove the cpp files from your question, they are not directly relevant for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Made some corrections and compiled the code,
Animal.h,

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>

class Zoo;
class Animal
{
  private:
    Zoo& zoo; // in which zoo
    std::string nom;  // name of an animal

  public:
    Animal(Zoo &z, std::string & n);
    std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

Zoo.h,

```
#ifndef ZOO_H
#define ZOO_H

#include <vector>
#include "Animal.h"
class Animal; 

class Zoo
{
  private:
    std::vector<Animal> animals;  // list of animals
  public:
    Zoo();
    void addAnimal(Animal & a);
    std::vector<Animal>  getAnimals();
};

#endif
```

Animal.cpp,

```
#include "Animal.h"

Animal::Animal(Zoo & z, std::string & n) : zoo(z), nom(n)
    { /* zoo = z; nom= n;*/
    }

std::string Animal::toString()
    {
        return nom;
    }
```

Zoo.cpp,

```
#include "Zoo.h"

Zoo::Zoo()
    {
        std::vector<Animal> animals(); // list of animals
    }

void Zoo::addAnimal(Animal &a)
    {
        animals.push_back(a); // add an animal to the zoo
    }

std::vector<Animal> Zoo:: getAnimals()
    {
        return animals;
    }
```

Main.cpp

```
   Zoo z;
   std::string nom("sheeta");
   Animal a(z,nom);
```

Changes are,
1) Zoo zoo; to Zoo& zoo; -> I think here you need to store the reference of the zoo than creating a new object, correct?

2) Correct the header inclusions to resolve the compilation errors as in the code below.

Comment: Those circular includes are terrible.  In a sane design, Animal.h only needs to predeclare `Zoo` not include Zoo.h  Then you had Animal.h include itself, which is pointless, but does no harm.

Comment: ok for 1) but now "uninitialized reference..."..it seamss that all reference should be initialized in C++...I understandf better why the use of pointers are so frequent..., ok for 2)

Comment: but we are initializing the reference member in Animal::Animal(Zoo & z, std::string & n) : zoo(z), nom(n)

Comment: I changed the reference to Zoo because it needed to be initialized. It is now a pointer to Zoo.